# Movie recommendation engine that can import existing scores

Tags: web-apps, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for a movie recommendation engine (most likely it will be a webapp) with the ability to automatically import my preferences, which consists of hundreds of existing scores of movies, too many to enter one by one. E. g. I have text file:

```
Shawshank Redemption 9/10
The Godfather        7/10
... hundreds of lines
```

Supported import formats (txt, csv, xls) are not important: I can convert my scores locally.

I'm looking for an existing engine with a large enough user database so that the engine can give useful recommendations.

That is ridiculous, but I really don't know about any engine with such useful feature, except [KinoPoisk.ru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KinoPoisk), from which I want to export scores :)

Comment: As of is this website or webapp, I find [this definition](https://twitter.com/btaroli/status/2817931830362112) really good: it's webapp if it "performs tasks on behalf of a user". In this case, the question definitely asks for app (/service) that performs a task (movie recommendations) on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [IMdb importer](https://github.com/tomzx/imdb-importer), implemented in PHP. I did not test this, it might be outdated already; last updated 9 months ago (May 2013). I have been happy with IMdb recommendations, but you might have different experience. If you are not, after importing ratings to IMdb, you can easily import those to [iCheckmovies](https://www.icheckmovies.com/) (related [blog post](https://www.icheckmovies.com/blog/importing+your+imdb+votes/)).

The data format for IMdb importer is really simple: JSON with list of dictionaries, containing vote and titles. Using only titles instead of title+release year pairs will obviously cause at least some problems, unless you only watched movies that does not have older releases.

I checked out the [source code](https://github.com/tomzx/imdb-importer/blob/master/importer.php); it's relatively well documented and well written, so updating or fixing it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

[Listal](http://www.listal.com/about) creates recommendations by basically averaging out the votes of users you pick into a top list. It does find users with similar tastes for you but I usually just look for a favorite underrated movie and pick people from there. Listal definitely has an import and export function. "edit profile" -> the import tab is to the right. can take XML or directly from imdb

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer is damaged if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

[Smovault](http://smovault.blogspot.com/p/features.html) is a software that should work for you.
It is *free* for personal use.
It uses [TMDb](https://www.themoviedb.org/) to download movie data like cast, crew, posters, etc and also provides movie recommendations based on your taste.
It has a bulk import option, but that requires that you have folders named by the movie, instead of a text file.
You can however create a small script/code to automatically create folders from your text file and then use Smovault to associate these folders to movies.

[DISCLOSURE] - I am the developer of Smovault.